# Extracting giant component

Tags: r, networking, components, igraph

I am currently conducting a network analysis. One of the variables I need to complete this analysis, is the giant component (the component in the network with the biggest share of nodes and edges).

The 'R Manual' (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/CINNA/versions/1.0.0/topics/giant.component.extract) provided me with the following code:

```
giant.component.extract(x, directed = TRUE, bipartite.proj = FALSE, num.proj = 1)
```

I have tried to adapt this code to my network by replacing 'x' with 'Network' (the igraph network I created earlier), which made the code look like this:

```
giant.component.extract(Network, directed = FALSE, bipartite.proj= FALSE, num.proj = 1 )
```

The problem here is, that I don't receive any output. Instead, I get the following error:

> Error in giant.component.extract(Network, directed = FALSE,
>   bipartite.proj = FALSE,  : could not find function
>   "giant.component.extract"

It is important to note that I have installed and opened the igraph package from my library. My 'Network' is a 'Large igraph (10 elemnents, 1.1mb)', created from a dataframe with 7321 observations of 4 variables.

Could someone please tell me why this code is not working for me? Other ways to achieve the same result would be appreciated too! Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is part of the `CINNA` package: `install.packages("CINNA")` then load the package `library(CINNA)` then re run the function.

Comment: @JohnCoene Thank you for your reply. I installed and read the package, but I am still getting the same error message.. Could there maybe be a conflict between packages? Currently I have igraph, dplyr, plyr, network, sna, ndtv, RcolorBrewer, openxlsx and CINNA opened, which is quite a lot I think... However, I don't know much about conflicts between packages and I can't find any information on this subject in the textfile that goes with the CINNA package [link]https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CINNA/CINNA.pdf

Comment: If there is a conflict, try running the function with `CINNA::giant.component.extract(pass, your, arguments)`. This will ensure you use the function from that package.

Comment: Trying this method gives me the following message: "Error: giant.component.extract' is not an exported object from 'namespace:CINNA'." On another post I found that putting in ":::"might help as well.. but then it just returns to the first error message. Thank you by the way for taking the time to answer these relatively easy questions.

Comment: What do get when you run `conflicts()`? and `search()`?

Comment: > conflicts()
 [1] "is.discrete" "arrange" "count" "desc" [5] "failwith" "id" "mutate" "rename" [9] "summarise" "summarize" "%>%" "%c%" [13] "%s%" "add.edges" "add.vertices" "as_data_frame" [17] "betweenness" "bonpow" "closeness" "components" [21] "degree" "delete.edges" "delete.vertices" "dyad.census" [25] "evcent" "get.edge.attribute" "get.edges" "get.vertex.attribute" [29] "groups" "hierarchy" "is.bipartite" "is.connected" [33] "is.directed" "list.edge.attributes" "list.vertex.attributes" "neighborhood" [37] "set.edge.attribute" "set.vertex.attribute" "triad.census" "union"

Comment: [41] "decompose" "df" "filter" "lag" [45] "spectrum" "data" "body<-" "intersect" [49] "kronecker" "order" "setdiff" "setequal" [53] "union"

Comment: > search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv" "package:openxlsx" "package:RColorBrewer" "package:ndtv"          
 [5] "package:animation" "package:networkDynamic" "package:sna" "package:statnet.common" [9] "package:network" "package:plyr"           "package:dplyr" "package:igraph" [13] "package:CINNA" "tools:rstudio"          "package:stats" "package:graphics" [17] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"          "package:datasets" "package:methods" [21] "Autoloads" "package:base" .    Sorry for doing it like this... uploading my image didn't work

Comment: I think you have an updated version of the package see the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CINNA/vignettes/CINNA.html#giant-component-extraction), try `giant_component_extract(zachary)`.

Comment: Thank you, that generated some output. I have to more short questions I hope you you can help me with. Could you maybe direct me to a file/thread that helps me interpret this output? The file above didn't mention anything about this unfortunately.. And do you know how I can see the top of my console, where the output begins?

Comment: Alt. Method: Manually extract giant component by `components <- decompose(Network, min.vertices=2)
sapply(components, diameter)` Then the one with the largest diameter is the giant component.

Answer (score 1):

replace all the periods with underscore

`g_comp <- giant_component_extract(g, directed = FALSE, bipartite_proj= FALSE, num_proj = 1 )`

then

`plot(g_comp[[1]]`